# How to remove elements in a list after a specific element in Python list (slice not applicable)

Tags: python, list

I have a python list shown below. I want to remove all the elements after a specific character `''`

Note1: The number of elements before `''` can vary. I am developing a generic code.

Note2: There can be multiple `''` I want to remove after the first `''`

Note3: Slice is not applicable because it supports only integers

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you very much.

```
['iter,objective,inf_pr,inf_du,lg(mu),||d||,lg(rg),alpha_du,alpha_pr,ls',
 '0,8.5770822e+000,1.35e-002,1.73e+001,-1.0,0.00e+000,-,0.00e+000,0.00e+000,0',
 '1,8.3762931e+000,1.29e-002,1.13e+001,-1.0,9.25e+000,-,9.86e-001,4.62e-002f,2',
 '5,8.0000031e+000,8.86e-010,1.45e-008,-5.7,1.88e-004,-,1.00e+000,1.00e+000h,1',
 '6,7.9999994e+000,1.28e-013,2.18e-012,-8.6,2.31e-006,-,1.00e+000,1.00e+000h,1',
 '',
 'Number,of,Iterations....:,6',
 '',
 '(scaled),(unscaled)',
 'Objective...............:,7.9999994450134029e+000,7.9999994450134029e+000',
 'Dual,infeasibility......:,2.1781026770818554e-012,2.1781026770818554e-012',
 'Constraint,violation....:,1.0658141036401503e-013,1.2789769243681803e-013',
 'Complementarity.........:,2.5067022522763431e-009,2.5067022522763431e-009',
 'Overall,NLP,error.......:,2.5067022522763431e-009,2.5067022522763431e-009',
 '',
 '',
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] including what you've already tried based on your own research. See [Why is "Can someone help me" not a valid question for stack overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: slicing is the normal way to do this... any reason why you don't want to use it?

Comment: @tdelaney Slice supports only integers and indices. Mine is a character like inverted comas

Comment: Its a list, so even though you may be searching for other characters, the actual list operation is with an integer index.

Comment: "Slice is not applicable because it supports only integers" You are right that slice **alone** won't solve the problem. You need to find a way to get the integer index of the element where you want to slice the list. When you figure out that piece, slice will be entirely applicable.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, I agree. But I am developing a generic code. The number of characters before that element could vary from file to file. So working on indices is not practical.

Comment: @RuaGoa You can't work with a *fixed* index because each line or file varies. But that doesn't mean you can't work with indexes at all. You can calculate the index for each line using some other method and then use a slice.

Comment: Can you post an example that won't work with slicing?

Comment: "vary from file to file" - Is this list the lines of a file? You could do the work as you read the file and reduce the total number of lines read.

Comment: @RuaGoa The thought process here goes something like this: "I can solve this problem with a slice if only I knew the integer index of the `''` where I want the slice to end. So how do I get the index of an element in a list?" Now you have a different question than the one you ask here that is googleable.

Comment: Alternatively, you can visit [the official documentation for Python lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and scan the methods that are available to find something useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd', 'e']
list = list[:list.index('')]
#list is now ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Explanation: `list.index('')` finds the first instance of `''` in the list. `list[:x]` gives the first `x` elements of the list. This code will throw an exception if `''` is not in the list.

Comment: It would be good to wrap that in a try/except for ValueError in case there isn't a "" in the list.

Comment: This deletes a slice and OP says no to slicing. I think this is the right answer but we'll have to see what OP's problem is.

Comment: @tdelaney I think the OP says slice isn't applicable because it can't do the job alone. They miss that slice together with `index()` will do the job.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - Right, that's why I asked OP to clarify.

Comment: also might be worth re-assigning to the same list, i.e. `list[:]`

Comment: Thank you for helping out @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Thank you for helping out @tdelaney

Comment: Thank you for helping out @ThisIsAQuestion

Answer (score 0):

You have a list and want to delete everything after a value that meets some sort of criteria. You can enumerate the list, searching for that value and delete the remaining slice. `list.index` will tell you the index of value that exactly matches some object like `""`.

```
test = ["foo", "bar", "" "baz", "", "quux"]
try:
    del test[test.index("")]
except ValueError:
    pass
```

If you have a more complex criteria, you can do your own scan

```
test = ["foo", "bar", " % " "baz", "", "quux"]
for i, val in enumerate(test):
    if "%" in val:
        del test[i:]
        break
```

If this list is really file, you could look for the value as you read and short-circuit.

```
test = []
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "":
            break
        test.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should find the first time `''` shows, by using `mylist.index('')`. This will indeed find the first show of it, as in `index()`'s documentation:

> Return first index of value.

Also, note the rest of the documentation:

> Raises ValueError if the value is not present.

Make sure to catch the error (or add `''` to the end of your list beforehand).

Now you can use slice `mylist[:mylist.index('')]`, or if you don't want to use it:

```
output = []
for i in range(mylist.index('')):
    output.append(mylist[i])
mylist = output
```